# Load markdown file into HTML's textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I'm trying to use [Remark.js](https://github.com/gnab/remark) to create HTML presentations based on the template provided. The template includes the `textarea` tag with `id='source'` where the markdown is simply copied in. I wanted to go for a solution where I can leave the template and just change the file that is loaded, so that I don't have to work inside the HTML file and keep the markdown separate.

I've tried using jQuery (I'm a noob) but it does not seem to work, the page stays empty. Here's what I tried:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>My presentation</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='presentation.css'>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://gnab.github.io/remark/downloads/remark-latest.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <textarea id="source"> </textarea>

    <script>
      $('#source').load('presentation.md');
    </script>

    <script>
      var slideshow = remark.create();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't get any errors in the JS console, but I also don't see anything. When I simply copy the file into the `textarea` it works, as expected, so the markdown file is OK.

I ran Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` so that at least I don't get the cross-origin requests error. However, that is not satisfactory as I intend to place the HTML file (and the related files) in Dropbox. If possible, I don't want to run a web server locally as it's just a 'simple' HTML file with some text copied in from another file.

What's the best way to achieve this, i.e. copying in a file as-is?

Comment: Can you provide information on wether the provided answer did work or not?

Comment: It works. I still have to tell Chrome to allow local files but at least I can work on the content separately.

Comment: If you do not want this you should think about using something like xampp to run the script on localhost. By this you will not need to tell chrome to allow local files anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This willl solve your problem:

Create the remark after you loaded the data by adding the call to your callback function.

```
<script>
  $('#source').load('presentation.md', function() {
    var slideshow = remark.create();
  });
</script>
```